# Material theme editor plugin not opening

Tags: plugins, themes, editor, sketchapp

I've just installed the material theme editor from https://material.io/tools/theme-editor/ but when I click on Material > "Open theme editor" from my Sketch plugins tab, nothing opens. I know the plugin successfully installed because I can click on Material > "Upload to Gallery" and a window pops up, but nothing for opening the theme editor. The theme editor website says you need macOS High Sierra (10.13) or later, which I do have, so this can't be the issue.

Is anyone else having this issue or know how to resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you see any error message?

Comment: No error messages, nothing showed up at all

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I actually fixed it just now-- had to moved Sketch to the applications folder, then update Sketch and relaunch it.

Thought it might be helpful to post this though since theme editor is so new and there is virtually no help for issues like this currently out there.